# How to set window color by hex code in Windows8?

Tags: colors, windows-8, user-interface

In Windows8 you can set window color from following path

```
Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization\Color and Appearance
```

This has some predefined colors and a Color Mixer option. I would like to explicitly set a color by hex or rgb code, but the color mixer's slidebars don't give me the specificity I need. Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for [Windows 7](http://tweaks.com/windows/39028/change-color-of-glass-with-regedit-with-decimal-to-hex-argb-converter/), but perhaps the registry remains mostly the same?

Try looking under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM`

You might also have luck looking under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel`...

Comment: When you change colors the first key does update. Specifically `ColorizationColor` and `ColorizationAfterglow`. Unfortunately I don't know how to map those to colors. They are hex values.

Comment: The page I link to has a little section at the bottom where you can input either decimal (0 to 255) or hex (00 to FF) for ARGB and it'll give you the value to put in. Does that help?